# Sticky header with columns width resizable

Tags: html, css

I am having a plain table. My header is not sticky. I tried multiple ways but it didn't work. My list is so big so I am planning to have a scroll bar only for the rows but not the header. My columns are resizable.

```
thead {
    display: table-header-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}


tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticky can be a bit tricky (sorry for the pun)

The thing here could be that both the sticky object and the parent needs to be a block. This however does not combine with your desire of the columns to be resizable.

I use a little jquery to combine best of both:

```
$('table, td, th, thead').width(function() {    
    return $(this).width();
});

$('td, th').height(function() { 
    return $(this).height();
});

$('table, thead').css('display','block')
```

This wayyour thead will stick (after you put in the right css)

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: -moz-sticky;
position: -ms-sticky;
position: -o-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0px;
```

(dont forget the top:0px !)